# How do I create a custom label for Labeling Function?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

How do I use LabelingFunction on a List of String Variables or a Function that generates String Variables? I want the List Plot to Display the individual elements of the List variable LabelString.

```
LabelString = Table[StringForm["Test # ``", LS], {LS, 1, 25}];

 ListPlot[Prime[Range[10]], LabelingFunction ->(LabelString[[#]] & ) , 
    ImageSize -> 900, Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

Gives

[image: LabelingFunction Result]

Comment: Check "LabelingFunction" under "Options" in the `ListPlot` documentation.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2448996).

Answer (score 4):

You need to write"LabelingFunction -> (LabelString[[#[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLHjq.png)]]] &)":

```
LabelString = Table[StringForm["Test # ``", LS], {LS, 1, 25}];
ListPlot[Prime[Range[10]], 
 LabelingFunction -> (LabelString[[#[[1]]]] &), Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I use this if I were to use DiscretePlot instead of Listplot?

Comment: Try e.g.: `dat = Prime[Range[10]];
DiscretePlot[dat[[n]], {n, 10}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (LabelString[[#[[1]]]] &), ImageSize -> 900, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Web"]`

Answer (score 4):

Or, simply

```
ListPlot[Prime[Range[10]] -> LabelString[[;; 10]], ImageSize -> 900, 
    Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

[image]

The length of the label list must equal the length of the data list, hence `LabelString[[;; 10]]`.  The option, `LabelingFunction`, can be used to specify the location of the labels relative to the data points, if desired.

Comment: How do I use this if I were to use DiscretePlot instead of Listplot?

Comment: @L_R_G_2021 The method illustrated in my answer does not carry over directly to `DiscretePlot`.  However, a simple alternative is `DiscretePlot[Labeled[Prime[n], LabelString[[n]]], {n, 10}, ImageSize -> 900, Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Web"]`.  A third argument can be added to `Labeled` to specify the location of the data label.

Comment: @L_R_G_2021 `Labeled` can be replaced by `Callout` in my previous comment with almost identical results.  This latter approach is very similar to that of @BobHanson.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html)

```
ListPlot[
 Callout[Prime[#],
    StringForm["Test # ``", #],
    Above] & /@ Range[10],
 ImageSize -> 900,
 Filling -> Axis,
 PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

[image]

Comment: How do I use this if I were to use DiscretePlot instead of Listplot?

Comment: `DiscretePlot[Callout[Prime[n], StringForm["Test # ``", n], Above], {n, 1, 10}, ImageSize -> 900, PlotTheme -> "Web"]`